# Email in Outlook (Exchange account) is shown thousands of times

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, exchange-2016

We have an account for an info@ email. Usually we get some spam, but we saw in the last days that 1 email is shown thousands of times.

But in fact the email arrives only once... I can see that because we have a Daemon that collects all mail via POP3 and sends them to Exchange.

This email is only once in our logs. What is Exchange doing here.

I can delete them but they show up again a view minutes later.

The message Id and the header files of the message show me that this is only 1 mail shown now >10000 times.

[image]

We are using Exchange 2016. And the latest CU and security packs are installed.

EDIT: I compared the complete header section of 4 emails. They are completely equal.

EDIT2: The emails are visible over OWA and the Outlook Client.

Comment: Do you mean receiving the spam repeatedly, or is it repeated after deleting the message and then it recovered? And does this issue occur in OWA?

Comment: It has been a while and I am writing to see how things are going on with this issue. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back.